# Backup volume and Data on the same raid array?

Tags: virtual-machines, raid10

I have to setup a server with three VMs. It must also act as first backup storage location.
The server is equipped with 8x1,8TB HDDs.

I'm not sure if it's a good choice to have one big raid10 with both vHDDs and Backup or create two RIAD10 array:
1) 4x1,8TB for vHDD
2) 4x1,8TB for backup

What do you suggest?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a backup, make a separate RAID for the backup.

The setup I would use is:
4xHDDs in RAID10 for usage and 4xHDDs in RAID 5 for backup, as it would give you additional space for multiple backups and still have redundancy.